# how to get all columns name from multiple table in a dataset by LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

i have multiple table in dataset so now i have to get all there coloumns name from the datatable.
Is it possible to do by Linq though I m using for Loops for getting the column name.

Comment: What are you using? DataReader, EF, NHibernate?

Comment: @ysrb what difference does it make _how_ the `DataTable` was populated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var columns = dataSet.Tables
                     .Cast<DataTable>()
                     .SelectMany(t=>t.Columns
                                     .Cast<DataColumn>()
                                     .Select(c=>c.ColumnName));
```

or if you want the table name as well

```
var columns = dataSet.Tables
                     .Cast<DataTable>()
                     .SelectMany(t=>t.Columns
                                     .Cast<DataColumn>()
                                     .Select(c=> new {
                                                      t.TableName, 
                                                      c.ColumnName
                                                     }
                                            )
                                 );
```

The `Cast<>` is necesary to turn the non-generic `IEnumerable` `Tables` and `Columns` properties into `IEnumerable<T>` types that can be used in Linq queries.

Comment: hi stanley, can you please tell me what changes should be made if i want data also..

Answer (score 3):

LINQ without loops

```
  var columnNames = (from table in dataSet.Tables.OfType<DataTable>()
                from column in table.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>()
                select column.ColumnName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();

foreach (DataTable item in dataSet.Tables)
{
    result.AddRange(item.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(i => i.ColumnName).ToList());
}
```